# Can I delete a push notification from a device which have receive this push notification?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, xcode-6.2, ios8.2

I have the following problem.

I look for a capability to delete a push notification from a device (iPhone respectively Apple Watch) but this device have receive the push notification.

The use case is that a USER A send a request to all available USER Bs. A push notification is send to all these USER Bs. At the moment the push notification arrive it will shown on their Apple Watch. One of the USER Bs answer that he accept this request. After he press the button to accept the request the notification should be deleted on all the other devices.

I really do not know a capability to do this.

But I know that you can handle this problem in Android as provide a unique ID for this notification. After that you can delete the other notifications with this particular ID.

Is their maybe a same way for iOS like it is provided in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with WatchKit/Apple Watch.

To answer your main question: no, you can't do this as it describe. Once you fire off a notification, it's in the user's hands to decide what they want to do with it.

As an alternative, you could maintain an "inbox" with every notification in your app and use the notification to prompt the user to check it. That way you could remove a notification from the inbox on the server side of things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yesterday we have the same idea with the inbox. It is nice to know that other developers also recommended this way. We will discuss this kind of solution.